# Duplicate the first row and the first column of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 3*3 matrix `A`

```
A = [1 2 3               
     4 5 6 
     7 8 9];
```

I want to duplicate only the first row and column of this matrix. It should look like

```
  1 1 2 3

  1 1 2 3

  4 4 5 6

  7 7 8 9
```

can someone tell how can i do this in matlab

Answer (score 10):

I think this is a good way just using indexing

```
A([1, 1:end], [1, 1:end])
```

Comment: That's a very elegant answer, I'll remember that approach. Although I guess there is still a concatenation used to get the subscripting vectors ^^

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by concatenating different parts of the original matrix:

```
B=[A(1) A(1,:);A(:,1) A];
```

In this expression A(1) is the top left element of A, A(1,:) is the first row and A(:,1) is the first column.

See the documentation on the [colon operator](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/colon.html).

Answer (score 2):

A bit late in the game, but worthwhile answering. You can use [`padarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/padarray.html) for that :

```
B = padarray(A,[1 1],'replicate','pre')
```

It's a one liner and more generic if you want to add more than just a single first and column ...

Answer (score 1):

In the code below, A is your starting point and I believe E is what you want to achieve.

You can of course combine all the intermediate expressions to achieve the final result in one step.

```
A= [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]
B= A(1:3,1:1)
C= [B A]
D= C(1:1,1:4)
E= [D;C]
```

Comment: And `1:3` can just be `:` and then later `1:4` can also just be `:`